# facebook like button: An error occurred with Facebook Platform Opt In. Please try again later

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to add a Facebook like button in my website.

If I use the following code like button is working but on log in the error message : "An error occurred with Facebook Platform Opt In. Please try again later" is displayed.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=guiuiu"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why this is happening. Do I need to create a fb API for successful login?

Comment: That's because the user (you?) who's trying to use the like button has completely disabled platform, including the Like button, in their privacy settings - the 'platform opt in' app is the mechanism by which you can change that setting directly from a Like button - if that's not working for some reason, re-enable it directly in your privacy settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must provide a valid url in order to work with the iframe method.

Anyway - you better use the xfmbl implementation of the like button

in order to do that you will have to open application (on http://developers.facebook.com/apps)

then paste this code after the `<body>` tag of your page (put the APP ID where it belongs)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID_GOES_HERE";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

add this namespace to your `html` node:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

and put this instead of the iframe you used

```
<fb:like send="false" href="YOUR_PAGE_ABSOLUTE_URL" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

for any further information you may refer here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong.

You'll get the same error the OP described no matter what implementation you use. The issue is due to a bug on Facebook's side of things.

It's currently OPEN, ASSIGNED, and set to HIGH priority. See here for more details: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228506407275556