# What is wrong with this FB Like URL?

Tags: facebook

Here's the URL I am generating:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/optin?_path=optin&app_id=127760087237610&display=touch&secure=false&social_plugin=like&return_params=%7B%22href%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2F2012%2Fnews%2F10%2F01%2Fandrew-bynum-out-three-weeks.ap%2Findex.html%22%2C%22send%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22layout%22%3A%22button_count%22%2C%22width%22%3A%2290%22%2C%22show_faces%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22like%22%2C%22colorscheme%22%3A%22light%22%2C%22font%22%3Anull%2C%22height%22%3A%2221%22%2C%22ret%22%3A%22optin%22%2C%22act%22%3A%22connect%22%7D&login_params=%7B%7D&from_login=1&client_id=127760087237610&refid=9

Decoded it looks like this:

`https://m.facebook.com/dialog/optin?_path=optin&app_id=127760087237610&display=touch&secure=false&social_plugin=like&return_params={"href":"http://www.nba.com/2012/news/10/01/andrew-bynum-out-three-weeks.ap/index.html","send":"false","layout":"button_count","width":"90","show_faces":"false","action":"like","colorscheme":"light","font":null,"height":"21","ret":"optin","act":"connect"}&login_params={}&from_login=1&client_id=127760087237610&refid=9`

When you use the first link, you'll (possibly) see an error that says "An error occurred with Facebook Platform Opt In. Please try again later."

I have no idea why. Do you? :)

Comment: And just so you're aware, I did read this thread, but no answers were truly provided:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384215/facebook-like-button-an-error-occurred-with-facebook-platform-opt-in-please-tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an open bug within the Facebook Platform.

See here for details: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/472857639400931

Answer (score 1):

The 'Facebook Platform Opt In' app is used when a user who has disabled platform via their privacy settings attempts to use a social plugin like the Like button - you've likely encountered a bug or edge case with this, because on desktop i've previously tested that this works as expected:

- User has platform disabled (i.e no access is allowed to their account from apps)
- User tries to use a Like button
- User is prompted with a permissions dialog for the Platform Opt In app
- Once accepted, platform is re-enabled for that user and the Like button works

If you can replicate this not working reliably, you should file a bug report

Comment: So here's something else that's interesting... the error only happens when you click the link and you're required to LOG ON. After logging on, you're redirected to the link posted in the question and you see the error. Notice it takes you to the m.facebook.com URL...

If you're already logged on, there is no error.

Also, this is only happening on mobile devices. On the desktop (Chrome Browser), there's no error.

Comment: My answer is only correct in the 'it's not due to a bug' case, Noah linked to an active bug report which likely explains this message in your case